# TFS Build Error - path contains more than the allowed 259 characters

Tags: tfs

I am getting following error for path being longer than 260 characters. However, when counted the total characters in path are 235. Please see the below error :

```
Other Errors and Warnings
 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
 Exception Message: TF400889: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters: drop/_PublishedWebsites/Orchard.Web_Package/Archive/Content/C_C/a/src/projects/Orchard/dev/DevAltaf/Orchard/src/Orchard.Web/obj/Debug/Package/PackageTmp/Modules/BrentApart.BannerManager/Scripts/controllers/bannerAssignmentController.js. Specify a shorter path. (type VssServiceException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.FileContainerDropProvider.EndCopyDirectory(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CopyDirectory.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Inner Exception Details:

```
Exception Message: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters. (type PathTooLongException)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a get/ unpack of these files the "drop" folder name is expanded to the local device path. For example "c:/windows/dlddownloads/" which will put you over...

Also you don't need "Archive/Content/C_C/a/src/projects/Orchard/dev/DevAltaf/Orchard/src/Orchard.Web/obj/Debug/Package/PackageTmp/" in your path and it looks like this is the issue. I have never seen files from thisnparg included in the published website path...

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. This is not me creating the folder. I am using TF service and it is by default path created by TF build controller. Kindly suggest a way out of this mess.

Comment: This is not the default path. No web application I have ever built has this. You have something strange going on in your project that is causing this.

Comment: :) neither have I come across such issue before. Any pointer to look into? For info, I am building Orchard CMS and trying to deploy it on Azure as CI.

Comment: I would look at both the build and the solution. Those files should never make it into a drop folder unless they are checked in...

Comment: I believe the path should not include - "drop/_PublishedWebsites/Orchard.Web_Package/Archive/Content/C_" and should start from remaining portion. I am sure I've not set this path anywhere as with all other build I create.